# My First Time Seeing this, What is this specific IDE Fatal Error?

Tags: pycharm

I was trying to open a new project in Pycharm, when all of a sudden, my Pycharm closed entirely, and when I re-opened it, and created a new project, an error message "IDE FATAL ERROR" popped up, The Exact code of the error is: " EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc000005)

would this endanger my current projects in any way?
(P.S. This is the first time I've encountered something like this)

Comment: What version of PyCharm are you using? Are you on Linux/Windows/macOS?

Comment: I am using PyCharm Community Edition ver.3.9, and I am on Windows.

Comment: (That is Pycharm 2021.2.2